# sed substitution variable containing "/"

Tags: bash, sed, string-substitution

I've got a file containing information: eg:

```
Hello
START
{
toto=1
tata=2
}
STOP
```

I need to substitute what is between START and STOP by the content of a bash variable.

This works well using `sed \c` but my variable contains the `\` character that needs to be kept, and it's not the case.

my sed:

```
MY_VAR="it is 07\:00\:00"; sed -i "/START/,/STOP/c ${MY_VAR}" file
```

result:

```
Hello
it is 07:00:00
```

expected:

```
Hello
it is 07\:00\:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `sed -i "/START/,/STOP/c ${MY_VAR//'\'/'\\'}" file`

Comment: `sed` itself has no concept of variables or accepting parameters. This is just an example of creating a `sed` script using *shell* parameter expansion. The script contains a literal `\:`, which `sed` itself resolves to `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to replace first all `\` with `\\\`:

```
MY_VAR="it is 07\:00\:00"
MY_VAR="${MY_VAR//\\/\\\\}"
sed "/START/,/STOP/c ${MY_VAR}" file
```

Output:

```
Hello
it is 07\:00\:00
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for, I could'nt find the right number of \ to use :(